# c# richTextBox dynamic change as typing

Tags: c#, selectionchanging

My problem is to change dynamically a combination of two typed letters and transforming them towards a new replacing one letter. Suppose I type "cx", I want to get immediatelly the replacing to "ĉ". May someone supply me with a code on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **WinForms**...

Here's a quick example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0xB;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);

    private Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        replacements.Add("cx", "ĉ");
        replacements.Add("ae", "æ");
        // etc...
    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbAutoReplacements.Checked)
        {
            int prevStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            int prevLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
            SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);

            int index;
            int start;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in replacements)
            {
                start = 0;
                index = richTextBox1.Find(pair.Key, start, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                while (index != -1)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Select(index, pair.Key.Length);
                    richTextBox1.SelectedText = pair.Value;
                    index = richTextBox1.Find(pair.Key, ++start, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                }
            }

            richTextBox1.Select(prevStart, prevLength);
            SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
            richTextBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration. It worked almost fine. To reach the point I need it could not change the capital letters into lower letters and so on... I difined all replacements as so:replacements.Add("cx", "ĉ");
            replacements.Add("Cx", "Ĉ");
            replacements.Add("cX", "ĉ");
            replacements.Add("CX", "Ĉ");

            replacements.Add("gx", "ĝ");
            replacements.Add("Gx", "Ĝ");
            replacements.Add("gX", "ĝ");
            replacements.Add("GX", "Ĝ");

Comment: Is there a easy way to freeze the activity of the richTextBox_TextChanged since I want to convert back all the stuff to  'cx', CX, etc... again.

Comment: For the capital letters issue, change `RichTextBoxFinds.None` to `RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase`.

Comment: To give the user the ability to toggle on/off the auto-replacement feature, add a **CheckBox** to the form and check that in the code.

Comment: Great... It is almost done. Your solution was good enough, but it is still missing a small bit, since the text can be typed, but can't be edited without causing mistakes. If we forget to edit a letter in between the already typed letters, the substitution can be done, but it provokes a feed line in the text.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: The problem is when you have already a text and you decide to edit in the middle of the text, you can type the letter and it immediately changes it, but as it occupied 2 spaces, it keeps waiting in the second place and starts blending the letters. I let the solution for you to see in http://esperanto.brazilo.org/softvaro/Transformilo%20-v1.1.zip

Comment: Gotcha.  **Comment out** the `richTextBox1.Select(prevStart, prevLength);` line and see if that works as you expect.